# Enterprise GitHub "pages" without login?

Tags: github-pages, github-enterprise

I set up a GitHub [pages](https://pages.github.com/) project site using my organization's Enterprise account. The page is supposed to be public, but it still requires LDAP authentication. Is there a way to have it be *really* public?

Comment: make it public while creating your repo..

Comment: My repo is listed as "public", but still requires LDAP authentication. I guess the difference is that *anyone* with credentials can view, whereas private repos are only viewable by whitelisting specific users in the "settings" page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like your GitHub Enterprise is running in "Private Mode", from the admin UI:

> Private mode only allows users with accounts to access any part of your installation. The sign-up page will be disabled, as will anonymous clones over git://.

To change this an admin user would need to navigate to:

**your.enterprise.github.url/setup/settings**

And uncheck the "Private Mode" checkbox.

Comment: I just searched for this and fount my own question.  Wish I could upvote twice.  Thanks again, from 2019!